# solve $z'' = g + 1/z$. Any formula for z(x) is OK

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$z(x)'' = g + \frac{1}{z(x)}$$
g: constant, 9.8m/s<sup>2</sup>
z(0), z'(0) can be anything. Let's set $z(0)=\alpha, z'(0)=\beta$
Any formula for z(x) is OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$Z''=g+\frac{1}{Z}$$
Multiply by $Z'$
$$Z'Z''=gZ'+\frac{Z'}{Z}$$
Using the chain rule you have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\frac{1}{2}(Z')^{2}-gZ-\ln(Z)\Big)=0$$
Hence
$$(Z')^{2}=c_{1}+2gZ+2\ln(Z)$$
Thus
$$t+c_{2}=\int^{Z}\frac{dZ'}{\pm\sqrt{c_{1}+2gZ'+2\ln(Z')}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Maple says
$$
\int ^{z \left( x \right) }\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\,gy+2\,\ln  \left( y
 \right) +C_1}}}{dy}-x-C_2=0
$$
and another one with the other square root.  This is what Kiryl got.

In cases like this, we only get an implicit expression for $Z(x)$.  Your DE textbook probably has a discussion of this possibility.

**added**
Initial condition $z(0) = \alpha$ lets us determine constant $C_2$:
$$
\int_\alpha^{z \left( x \right) }\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\,gy+2\,\ln  \left( y
 \right) +C_1}}}{dy}-x=0
$$
If my calculations are right, $z'(0)=\beta$ lets us determine constant $C_1$:
$$
\int_\alpha^{z \left( x \right) }\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\,g(y-\alpha)+2\,\ln  \left( y-\alpha \right) +\beta^2}}}{dy}-x=0
$$